# I'm injecting a dll into the program, after the injection I'm trying to get ntdll.dll ZqQueryInformationProcess, but the application crashes

Tags: c++, dll, dll-injection

Here is my code:

```
inline DWORD RestoreZwQueryInformationProcess() {
HMODULE ntdll = GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll");
DWORD ZwQueryInformationProcessAddr = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(
    GetProcAddress(ntdll, "ZwQueryInformationProcess"));

BYTE ZwQIP[] = {
    0xB8, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
BYTE* originalBytes = (BYTE*)ZwQueryInformationProcessAddr;

int i = 0;
for (BYTE _byte : ZwQIP) {
    *(BYTE*)(ZwQueryInformationProcessAddr + i) = _byte;
    i++;
}
return ZwQueryInformationProcessAddr;
}
```

In dllmain.cpp

```
RestoreZwQueryInformationProcess();
```

When calling that function, injected application is crashing.
Is it something about ntdll.dll permissions? I couldn't get it work.

Edit: My friend is using the same dll and the same injection method, and his application isn't crashing.

Comment: When you write crash what do you mean? Do you get any errors? Have you tried using applications such as Valgrind or a debugger?

Comment: I'm more suprised that it works for your friend, since you're writing in an executable section, which is usually read-only.

Comment: Ok, I know why my application was crashing. It's because I had bad syscalls offsets. Do you know hot to get them dynamicly?